# Why is my VBScript throwing nine Pop Ups instead of one?

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I have a Win7 64 bit Windows Professional Laptop. I have a VB Script taken from the net  and with certain alterations I am trying to  get  at Link speed for all Adaptors on my Laptop. The Vb script seems to be working except that I have to enter 9 times to get a complete list of all instances. This means that  when I double click the  script, the pop up shows only one instance. When I  press Enter again, it shows the  first and the second one, and likewise till I press Enter, nine times, I get the complete list, in one Pop Up. I know this is possible on the command prompt using CScript, but I prefer to get a single Popup. I am  not very versatile on VBScripts but I am willing to learn. Am I missing something ? Any help will be appreciated. Here's my script.

```
strComputer = "."
strRslt = Wscript.ScriptName _
    & vbTab & "Computer Information " & vbcr _ 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\WMI")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM MSNdis_LinkSpeed" ,,48)  
For Each objItem in colItems
strRslt = strRslt & vbNewLine  _
& "InstanceName: " & vbTab & objItem.InstanceName & vbcr _
& "NdisLinkSpeed: " & vbTab & objItem.NdisLinkSpeed/10 & " kbps" 
msgbox strRslt,&h51000, "speed"
Next
```

Comment: Move the line: `msgbox strRslt,&h51000, "speed"` after `Next` that way the popup won't show until after the loop has finished.

Comment: @Lankymart ~ barring the  last two lines, I've tried several ways to get  the script to work as desired but failed. Now with your suggestion, the script is working as desired.

Comment: @Lankymart Please turn your comment into a reply.
Rajdeep Very good quality question, welcome! Please accept Lankymart's reply.

Comment: @thecarpy ~ Please let me know how to 'Please accept Lankymart's reply.' ?? I read somewhere that we can't even say  thanks. .  +1 etc. Please guide me. I am new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is a simple one that many can make when first starting out with VBScript or other similar languages.

The `For Each` statement will iterate through a list of objects until it reaches the end of the list, in this case nine object instances. The command is structured in such a way that any commands within the `For` and `Next` block will be executed for the current instance that is identified by the variable after `Each`.
As the `MsgBox()` function is running inside the `For` it will be displayed for each object instance.

If you didn’t expect this the simple fix is to move the `MsgBox()` outside of the loop.

```
For Each objItem in colItems
    strRslt = strRslt & vbNewLine  _
    & "InstanceName: " & vbTab & objItem.InstanceName & vbcr _
    & "NdisLinkSpeed: " & vbTab & objItem.NdisLinkSpeed/10 & " kbps"
Next
msgbox strRslt,&h51000, "speed"
```

Comment: ~ The script is working fine.. and now with the  addition of ' vbInformation '  which I had not included earlier. The  purpose of  the script with ' &h51000 ' was to ensure that the  Pop up appears above all windows, otherwise what was happening  is that the  script would   complete with the  Pop up without me even knowing about it. And now with  ' vbInformation '  and the  sound of the  Popup, I  am put on alert. Can you confirm that the addition of ' &h51000 ' in scripts, is the only way to  ensure that  the pop up window appears over other windows ?

Comment: @Rajdeep read through [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/sfw6660x%28v%3dvs.84%29), that’s what it’s there for. You will be wanting `vbInformation + vbSystemModal` for an Win32 application wide modal popup with the Information icon.

Answer (score 1):

Because the variable `strRslt` populate data infos into for .. next loop

So, in this case, you should write your `MsgBox` after the `Next` and not inside the loop :

```
strComputer = "."
strRslt = Wscript.ScriptName & vbTab & "Computer Information"
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\WMI")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM MSNdis_LinkSpeed" ,,48)  
For Each objItem in colItems
    strRslt = strRslt & vbNewLine & _
    "InstanceName: " & vbTab & objItem.InstanceName & vbcrlf & _
    "NdisLinkSpeed: " & vbTab & objItem.NdisLinkSpeed/10 & " kbps" 
Next
MsgBox strRslt,vbInformation+&h51000, "speed"
```

Comment: Yeah, we [covered that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62147050/why-is-my-vbscript-throwing-nine-pop-ups-instead-of-one#comment109914597_62147050) an hour ago.

Comment: @Hakoo ~ Yes it didn't strike  that after the first instance,  the script would look for  more instances, which is only possible when it loops and goes back to the beginning of the script. Now with a single double click on the script, I get only one pop up.

Comment: @Rajdeep So if this answer your issue, don't forget to mark it as accepted !